# How can i format HTML document (some tags are breaked into two lines)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

```
  Cli:=THTTPClient.Create;
  Result:=Cli.Get(URL).ContentAsString;
  Cli.Free;
  Memo1.Text:=Result;
```

it worked ok, but some tags are breaked. I get it:

```
</div></div><div class="masthead_main container row"><div class="masthead_logo_search"><di
v class="masthead_logo"><a href="/">FAQs</a></div><div class="masthead_search"><form class="search" method="get" action="/search"
```

I need something like this:

```
...
</div>
</div>
<div class="masthead_main container row">
<div class="masthead_logo_search">
<div class="masthead_logo">
<a href="/">FAQs</a>
</div>
<div class="masthead_search">
<form class="search" method="get" action="/search">
...
```

I need not breaked tags. How can I get formated HTML?

Comment: I find it unlikely that the webserver would deliver broken HTML like that. Are you sure you are not simply seeing the Memo's word-wrapping in effect? If you save the HTML as-is to a file, is it still broken? Also, why do you need the HTML formatted a particular way?

Comment: Yes, i caught string(Result) via Debug and save it to file. and it is broken.
And i can't parse it. But if i delete all #13,#9. My Parse work well, but #13,#9 sometimes need to use in simple text.

Comment: "*if i delete all #13,#9. My Parse work well*" - well, then your parser is broken if it can't ignore insignificant whitespace. Fix that instead.

Comment: example i search Pos ('<div>', 'Result'). It can't fin it because div separated: <di#13#10v>

Comment: I though may be delphi has simple function that format HTML-code, like i used TJSONObject.Format or TJSONValue.Format

Comment: "*I though may be delphi has simple function that format HTML-code*" - no, it doesn't. In any case, you should use an actual HTML parser instead of rolling your own manually.

Comment: A linebreak is ``#13#10``, not ``#13#9``. ``#9`` is a ``Tab``!

Comment: Yes, i know. I did mistake in comment. 
Examples variative: '<di#13#10v>', and '<di#9v>', and '<d#13#10iv#9>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created function! it's working for me:

```
function RestoreTags(Source:String):String;
var
 TagString:String;
 I:Integer;
 PosS:Integer;
 Opened:Boolean;
begin
 Opened:=False;
 Result:='';

 for I:=1 to Length(Source)-1 do
   begin
    if Source[I]='<' then
    begin
     Opened:=True;
     PosS:=I;
    end
    else if Source[I]='>' then
    begin
     Opened:=False;
     TagString:=Copy(Source,PosS,I-PosS+1);
     TagString:=StripChars(TagString,[#9, #10, #13]);
     Result:=Result+TagString;
    end
    else if Opened=False then
    begin
     Result:=Result+Source[I];
    end
   end;


end;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).